# How to setup react-native-navigation with react-native-siri-shortcut (rootView issue)

Tags: react-native-navigation

Need some guidance on how to get [RNN](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/) to work with [react-native-siri-shortcut](https://github.com/Gustash/react-native-siri-shortcut#getting-started).
Please bear with me if my post is too verbose as I'm a noob with `xCode` and `objective C`, so don't want to miss anything out.

So I've got a couple of questions/problems with trying to get the 2 libraries to work together:

### 1. Setting up the `initialProperties` with a `RCTRootView`

`react-native-siri-shortcuts` sets up the app in `AppDelegate.m` like this:

```c
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
...
 // Check if the app launched with any shortcuts
    BOOL launchedFromShortcut = [launchOptions objectForKey:@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsUserActivityDictionaryKey"] != nil;
    //Add a boolean to the initialProperties to let the app know you got the initial shortcut
    NSDictionary *initialProperties = @{ @"launchedFromShortcut":@(launchedFromShortcut) };

    RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                        moduleName:@"doesthismatter"
                                                 initialProperties:initialProperties // Add the initial properties here
                                                     launchOptions:launchOptions];

...

}
```

In V2 of RNN, the rootView is not being used anymore, instead we just call:

```c
[ReactNativeNavigation bootstrap:jsCodeLocation launchOptions:launchOptions];
```

Therefore we are not able to pass the `initialProperties` through to the `rootView`.

### 2. Accessing the `rootView` in other parts of the code

Continuing on from the set up `react-native-siri-shortcut`:

```c
// This method checks for shortcuts issued to the app
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity
 restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> *restorableObjects))restorationHandler
{
  UIViewController *viewController = [self.window rootViewController];
  RCTRootView *rootView = (RCTRootView*) [viewController view];

  // If the initial properties say the app launched from a shortcut (see above), tell the library about it.
  if ([[rootView.appProperties objectForKey:@"launchedFromShortcut"] boolValue]) {
    ShortcutsModule.initialUserActivity = userActivity;

    rootView.appProperties = @{ @"launchedFromShortcut":@NO };
  }

  [ShortcutsModule onShortcutReceivedWithUserActivity:userActivity];

  return YES;
}
```

Since `RCTRootView` isn't being used to register our app, will this part of the code work?

I've already searched the repo for issues related to `initialProps` and `reactView` and the few issues that I did find, never got answered and were closed due to inactivity.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, searching for the `launchedFromShortcut` property on [github](https://github.com/Gustash/react-native-siri-shortcut/search?q=launchedFromShortcut&unscoped_q=launchedFromShortcut) I realised it's not consumed in the Javascript side. Therefore it's only usage is as *flag* to tell wether the app was launched from a shortcut and passing it to the RNN's `RNNReactRootViewCreator` seems unnecessary.

Removed that necessity the integration turned out to be pretty simple, we only need to add `launchedFromShortcut = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsUserActivityDictionaryKey] != nil;` to `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and check it's value on `continueUserActivity`.

The `AppDelegate.m` would look as follows:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <ReactNativeNavigation/ReactNativeNavigation.h>
#import <RNSiriShortcuts/RNSiriShortcuts-Swift.h>

@implementation AppDelegate
BOOL launchedFromShortcut;


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

  launchedFromShortcut = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsUserActivityDictionaryKey] != nil;
[ReactNativeNavigation bootstrap:jsCodeLocation launchOptions:launchOptions];

    //    
    // Regular RNN bootstrap code omitted for brevity sake
    //    

  return YES;
}


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity
 restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> *restorableObjects))restorationHandler
{

    if (launchedFromShortcut) {
        ShortcutsModule.initialUserActivity = userActivity;
        launchedFromShortcut = NO;
    }

    [ShortcutsModule onShortcutReceivedWithUserActivity:userActivity];
    return YES;
}

@end
```